# Are there finitely many primes $x$ such that for a fixed odd prime $p$, $n=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dotsb + x+1$ is composite and $x \mid \phi(n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

Let
\begin{equation} n =x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dotsb + x+1
\end{equation} where $x$ and $p$ are odd primes.

If $p$ is set to $5$, it appears $x=5$ is the only prime $x$ such that $n$ is composite and $x \mid \phi(n) $ (verified up to $x \le 2\cdot 10^6$). Setting $p$ to $7$, we get only two values of $x$; $x=7$ and $x = 281$.

If $x$ is allowed to take composite values, it appears there are infinitely many $x$ such that $x \mid \phi(n)$. Therefore, the following Conjecture is reasonable.

**Conjecture 1**

Let
\begin{equation} n =x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dotsb + x+1
\end{equation} where $x$ and $p$ are odd primes.
For a fixed odd prime $p$,  there are finitely many primes $x$ such that $x \mid \phi(n) $ with $n$ composite.

If Conjecture 1 is true, then, for a fixed prime $p$, there exists an upper bound $x_\text{max}$ such that $x \nmid \phi(n) $  for all $x>x_\text{max} $ with $n$ composite.

If Conjecture 1 is true, Theorem 1 gives a fast primality test for integers $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dotsb + x+1$ with $x > x_\text{max}$.

**Theorem 1**

Assuming Conjecture 1.  Let $n =x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\dotsb + x+1$ where $x$ and $p$ are odd primes with $x>x_\text{max}$. If there exists a positive integer $b$ such that $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and   $b^{(n-1)/x} \not\equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $n$ is prime.

Proof. Assuming Conjecture 1, we have $ x \mid \phi(n) $ if and only if $n$ is prime. Assume $n$ is composite. Using the properties of order of an integer, one can deduce that $ord_nb \mid (n-1) /x$. It follows that if $n$ is composite then $b^{(n-1)/x} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, contradicting our hypothesis. Therefore $n$ must be prime.

Note: As $x$ is prime then $x \mid \phi(n) $ implies $n = (ux+1)(vx+1)$ for some non negative integers $u$, $v$ with $ux+1$ prime. It can also be shown that $n = (sp+1)(tp+1)$ for some non negative integers $s$, $t$ with $sp+1$ prime. And from this post [Positive divisors of $P(x,n)=1+x+x^2+ \cdots + x^n$ that are congruent to $1$ modulo $x$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404875/positive-divisors-of-px-n-1xx2-cdots-xn-that-are-congruent-to-1-mo),
if $ux+1 \mid n$  then $ux+1 \mid \frac{ u^{p}+1} {u+1}$. Perhaps these observations might be useful in proving Conjecture 1 and establishing $x_\text{max}$.

Comment: It should be noted that your $n$ as constructed is a base-$x$ repunit. Repunits have a deep history of study that perhaps can be tapped into to answer the Conjecture.

Comment: Your title seems to ask about the number of $n$'s, whereas your body seems to ask about the number of $x$'s.  Is it clear that they are both finite, or both infinite?  Also, your title requires that $n$ is composite (with no assumption on $x$), whereas your body seems to require instead that $x$ is prime (with no assumption on $n$). \\ Finally, doesn't the usefulness of Theorem 1 require not just knowing that Conjecture 1 is true, but having an effective estimate for $x_\text{max}$?

Comment: One more thing:  TeX note:  please use $x \mid \phi(n)$ `x \mid \phi(n)` instead of $x\ |\ \phi(n)$ `x\ |\ \phi(n)`; and $b^{n - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ `b^{n - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod n` instead of $b^{n - 1} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$) `$b^{n - 1} \equiv 1$ (mod $n$)`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps you can check approaches to Agoh-Giuga conjecture, which if I'm not mistaken deals with the particular case $x=p$.

Comment: @LSpice, True Theorem  1 requires an effective estimate for $x_{max}$.

Comment: @Slyvain, Agoh-Giuga Conjecture is very different from Conjecture 1 even in the particular case $x=p$.

Comment: For $p=5$, has anyone found any prime $x>5 $ such that $n$ is composite and $x \ | \ \phi(n) $

Comment: From this post, 
  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404875/positive-divisors-of-px-n-1xx2-cdots-xn-that-are-congruent-to-1-mo, 
if $ux+1 \mid n$  then $ux+1 \mid \frac{ u^{p}+1} {u+1}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something since this is pretty advanced modular arithmetic, but I'm getting:  $\phi(n) = n \prod_{p \mid n} (p-1)/p$ so that if $\phi(n) = 0 \pmod x$, then that implies $n \prod_{p \mid n} (p-1) = 0 \cdot \prod p = 0 \pmod x$ and of course $n = 1 \pmod x$ so we get, if $x \mid \phi(n)$ then $x \mid \prod_{p \mid n} (p - 1)$ and of course the converse also holds (so it should be $\iff$) since you can multiply zero by $n / \prod_{p \mid n} p$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a proof of Conjecture 1 for the case $p=5$. The proof depends on the truth of the following overwhelmingly true unproven result :

Let
\begin{equation} P(x) = x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x+1. 
\end{equation}
Then all positive integers $x$ such that $P(x) $ has a proper divisor congruent to 1 modulo $x$ are given as follows :

Let $r(m)=m^2 +m-1$ and $q(m) = (r(m) +2)^2 - 2$, where $m$ is a positive integer. For a particular positive integer $m$, define sequences $A_n, B_n$ as follows:

$A_1 = m^3+2m^2 +2m$ ,
$A_2 = q(m)A_1+r(m)$,
$A_n = q(m)A_{n-1}-A_{n-2}+r(m)$

$B_1 = m^5+2m^4 +3m^3 + 3m^2 +m$ ,
$B_2 = q(m)B_1+r(m)-m$,
$B_n = q(m)B_{n-1}-B_{n-2}+r(m)$

Then all positive integers $x$ such that $P(x) $ has a proper divisor congruent to 1 modulo $x$ are given by $x=A_n$ and $x=B_n$, $n\ge 1$, $m \ge 1$.

It can be shown by induction that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are always composite except when $m=1$ and $n=1$ in which case $x=A_1=5$ is prime.

If the unproven result here is true (very likely the case), then Conjecture 1 is settled for the case $p=5$. (Having no proper divisor congruent to 1 modulo $x$ for all primes $x>5 $ implies $x \nmid \phi(P(x)) $ for all composites $P(x) $, $x >5 $ prime)

There's no reason to believe that the case $p=5$ is special. Conjecture 1 is most likely true for all odd primes.

**ADDED (Compositeness of $A_n$ and $B_n$)**

For $n \equiv 0, 1 \ (\mathrm{mod} 
 \ 3)$, it can be shown by induction that $m$ divides $A_n$ and $B_n$. And when
$n \equiv 2 \ (\mathrm{mod \ 3})$, one can prove that $m+1$ divides $A_n$ and $B_n$. Therefore it's clear that $A_n$ and $B_n$ are composite if $m>1$.

The remaining  case $m=1$ is interesting. When $m=1$, $A_n$ and $B_n$ are a product of two sequences i.e $A_n = f_n\cdot g_n$ where $f_1=1 , f_2 = 3, f_n = 3f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}$ and $g_1=5 , g_2 = 12, g_n = 3g_{n-1}-g_{n-2}$.

Similarly $B_n = f_n\cdot g_n$ but with initial values changed; $f_1 = 2, f_2= 5$ and $g_1 = 5, g_2 = 14$

So $x = A_1 = 5$ is the only prime $x$ such that $P(x) =x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x+1 $ contains a proper divisor congruent to $1$ modulo $x$

Comment: Original post on the unproven result  : 
   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403542/positive-integer-solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-z4z3-z

Comment: The proof of the case $p=5$ required finding a complete set of positive  integers $x$ such that $P(x) $ contains at least one  proper divisor congruent 1 modulo $x$ and then showing that $x$ is composite for all $x >5$.  For $p>5 $, we do not have such a set of positive integers $x$ at our disposal and finding it will most likely be very difficult. Proving or disproving  Conjecture 1 will therefore require a clever technique that does not require foreknowledge of the set of positive integers $x$ with this property.

Comment: I have finally proved the case $p=5$ without relying on the unproven result. I have even got interesting results for the more general case $P(x) =x^4+c_1x^3 +c_2x^2 +c_3x+1$, thanks to a paper suggested by one of the users here. Are there any other papers that investigate divisors of  $P(x) = x^n+c_1x^{n-1}+\cdots + c_{n-1}x+1$, $n \ge 5$, that are congruent to $1$ modulo $x$?